# Does LokiJS supports ISO-8601 date format?

Tags: javascript, iso8601, lokijs

When storing a date in ISO-8601 format (a string), will the date operators (*$dteq, $dtgte, $dtlte*) work out-of-the-box? Or all my children are cursed by javascript date?

Oddhinn Blessadur!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source on [github](https://github.com/techfort/LokiJS) (great thing about open source), no. I mean, `$dteq` works because it just delegates to a general purpose equality test, and the strings match, but `$gte`/`$lte` (there's no `$dtgte`/`$dtlte` but if I assume you meant those) will try to treat the strings as numbers, which won't work.

If you stored the dates as numbers (milliseconds-since-The-Epoch), that would work. Or of course, as `Date` instances.

Comment: Thanks for checking the source code, I will use the number approach instead.